# I have to replace the defined block or placeholder place in php and copy to the other file

Tags: php, templates, copy, placeholder

Actually, I would like to copy a template file where I define some block and dynamically put the content there and copy the whole content to another file.  Suppose I create a template file named as demo.php in the demo.php I defined it as:

```
<div class="container">
     %Placeholder%
</div>
```

and when I need I can put the content there and create new with whole the content of this template file.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You should be able to find many examples of that online. And ^

Comment: I want to create a file dynamically but having the same design so I have defined a prototype but I have someplace where I put the contents dynamically suppose I have created a template having some header and footer but content will be added dynamically to the newly created file

Comment: why do you want to create a new file with same contents at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a global template page which will be inherited in all of your other pages.

**global.php**

```
<header>
  //header goes here
</header>
<sidebar>
  //sidebar goes here
</sidebar>
```

**someotherPage.php**

```
  include_once('global.php');
  //your search template
```

**For Instance**

Facebook includes header and sidebar on each page.

Hope this helps. Sorry for the formatting. Using a mobile device to answer.

Comment: suppose have a bootstrap template file and I want to create user add functionality then I will call the template and replace the block content with my form which I will create dynamically same for update form and many other operations like search, add etc.

Comment: For that you have to create a global template page and include it in as many pages as you want.